# Nothing happens when I run this prime factors program

Tags: python, printing, factors

Beginner here. I run this Python code that's supposed to find and print the prime factors of any number (in this case it is 16), but nothing comes up in the console. Help!

```
def is_not_prime(x):
    for i in range(2,x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return True
            break
        else:
            return False

def prime_factors(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            x = i
            primes.append(x)
            break
        y = n / x
        return y

primes = []

def main(y):
    while is_not_prime(y):
        prime_factors(y)
    primes.append(y)
    print(primes)

main(16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```
while is_not_prime(y):
    prime_factors(y)
```

`16` is not prime so you are stuck in an infinite `while True` loop here.

If you want to break out of this loop, you are going to need to change `y` inside the loop somehow.

Comment: I thought I change `y` inside of the `prime_factors` function?

Comment: Changing `y` inside the local scope of `prime_factors` function, has no effect on the `y` in the local scope of `main` function.

Comment: Okay thanks. I fixed that issue by putting the actual function `prime_factors` inside of the `while` loop and changing `y` at the end of it, but now I've found out that the actual program doesn't return the correct answers so I'll have to keep looking at it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Instead of putting the function explicitely inside the while loop, you could do something like `y = prime_factors(y)` in every loop.